# How to trim all whitespace and new line characters at end of UITextView's string

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring, uitextview

I've seen other questions on here on how to remove all whitespace and newline characters using the actual NSString methods, but those affect the beginning of the string, which I do not want.

So let's say for example my user types the following string into my UITextView: H  E  Y  \n  \n

There are two spaces after the letter Y followed by a new line character, two more spaces, and lastly another new line character in the above example.

What I would like is for everything after the letter Y to be removed from the UITextView's string.

I'd appreciate any pointers to help me solve this.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
     textView.text = [self removeCrapFrom:textView.text];
}

- (NSString *)removeCrapFrom:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger location = 0;
    unichar charBuffer[[string length]];
    [string getCharacters:charBuffer];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = [string length]; i >0; i--)
    {
        if (![[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:charBuffer[i - 1]])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return  [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, i  - location)];
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with the other answers?

Comment: Like I said, they affect the beginning and end, which I DO NOT want

Comment: Then why didn't you post an example of a string with whitespace/characters at the beginning?

Comment: I did actually. H E Y  \n \n was the example.

Comment: I don't see any white space before that.

Comment: Why is it needed? It doesn't effect my question.

Comment: No, but it vastly improves it because it makes it a million times more clear that the whitespace at the beginning is important to keep.  For example, in the link from my possible duplicate comment, the question is identical to yours, but the accepted answer it an NSString method that will trim from both answers.

Comment: Link posted didn't help

Comment: How didn't it help? I think the downvoters would beg to differ with you.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can use:

```
NSString *newString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

I tested in Xcode with:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.text = @"H E Y \n \n";
textView.text = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"textView.text = [%@]",textView.text);
```

Result is:

```
textView.text = [H E Y]
```

Comment: Please read the question and the discussion in the comments.